# When does ASP.NET Identity create its tables inside an existing database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

For my web application I use the code first approach, all the code related to DB access resides in a different project (Infrastructure) however. All the ASP.NET Identity stuff is by default in the web project. I know I can point ASP.NET Identity to my existing database by changing the connection string like so:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyDatabase", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

   ...
}
```

However, calling into AccountController gives me an error:

> InvalidOperationException: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

The error occurs on sign in

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

and the stack trace reveals

> System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType) +137
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +36
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +79
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +28
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +56
>      System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +127
>      System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +156
>      Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext() +468
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
>      Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +75
>      Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__29.MoveNext() +361

Looking at the database with SQL Server Management Studio I can see that the tables for Identity haven't been created, so now I'm wondering what exactly triggers the creation of the required tables. Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: You will have to [create the tables yourself](http://danieleagle.com/blog/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/#Step_4_8211_Generate_SQL_Scripts_For_Each_Database_Table)

Comment: I had a feeling I have to, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a solution of my own, after having studied the source code for ASP.NET Identity v2. The problem - in my case anyway - was that the DbContext was in a project different from the web project. However, as ASP.NET Identity uses its own context that inherits from `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` the mappings for that context were never applied and so it started looking for `ApplicationUser` in the context, which didn't exist, of course. That is what the error message is all about.

Here's a code snippet taken from ASP.NET `IdentityDbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<TUser>(b =>
    {
        b.HasKey(u => u.Id);
        b.HasIndex(u => u.NormalizedUserName).HasName("UserNameIndex");
        b.HasIndex(u => u.NormalizedEmail).HasName("EmailIndex");
        b.ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        ...
    }
}
```

So the user type (e.g. `ApplicationUser`) is mapped to `AspNetUsers` in your database, which means the moment you see the error message

> InvalidOperationException: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

it means the mapping from `IdentityDbContext` was not applied and you're querying against `ApplicationUser` instead of `AspNetUsers`.

My solution was to create a separate folder that holds the identity context as well as its migrations:

[image: Project housing 2 DbContexts]

I was then in a position to create the database and all its tables, including the ASP.NET Identity ones by issueing

```
PM> update-database -ConfigurationTypeName BlogContextConfiguration
PM> update-database -ConfigurationTypeName PortalContextConfiguration
```

No manual intervention, SQL scripts etc. required.

[image: All tables created with no manual intervention]

This may also work with existing databases, but I haven't checked that so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article:

Setting Up ASP.NET Identity Framework 2.0 with Database First

http://danieleagle.com/blog/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/

It helped me implement Identity Framework in my own DB